# How to append 2D grayscale images to 4D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a series of grayscale images I am trying to append to a single 4D array. The 2 additional dimensions represent a user and a photo number. There are 1,000 users and each user has 10 photos.

I am attempting to preprocess each image one by one, and then appending to an *all_imgs* array that has all photos for all users.

In order to append image #1 for user 1,001, I tried adding two dimensions to the original image and then appending it to *all_imgs*, but still does not work.

```
In[1]: img.shape
Out[1]: (128, 128)

In[2]: all_imgs.shape
Out[2]: (1000, 10, 128, 128)

In[3]: img[None,None,:,:].shape
Out[3]: (1, 1, 128, 128)

In[4]: np.append(all_imgs, img[None,None,:,:], axis=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/blah/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-29-b82fcbdc4f61>", line 1, in <module>
    np.append(all_imgs, img[None,None,:,:], axis=0)
  File "/Users/blah/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 5003, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Any suggestions to a python beginner?

Comment: Look at `numpy.stack`. This is what you want I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't append a single image to `all_imgs`, because you'd introduce a new user with space for 10 images. You'd need to assign the other 9 images as well.

Instead, I'd suggest to first expand the 4D array

```
all_imgs = np.append(all_imgs, np.zeros((1, 10, 128, 128)), axis=0)
```

and to assign the one image (image `0` of user `1000`) afterwards:

```
all_imgs[1000, 0, :, :] = img
```